# Are Tzitzis obligated in Tzitzis

Tags: clothing, tzitzis, mourning-aveilus, tallit-gadol, tallit-katan

According to the [Rosh (Moed Katan 3:43)](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_on_Moed_Katan.3.43.1?lang=he), a garment worn solely to absorb sweat is not considered a בגד (with regard to the obligation of מצות קריעה - mournful rending). This principle is invoked by later authorities to exempt four-cornered undershirts from *tzitzith* (see, e.g., *Tekhelet V'Argaman* 5, s.v. *apikresin*, citing Rav Chaim Kanievski; *Shu"t Chemdath Tzvi* 3:3; and *Shevet Miyehudah, Ki Teitzei*, cited [here](http://dinonline.org/2011/08/25/perftzis-undershirt-tzitzis/)).  Seemingly, even those who argue, agree that this is because the undershirt does have functional garment benefits (ibid):

> Yet, it does not appear that our undershirts are made solely for the purpose of absorbing sweat, for they also serve to provide a degree of warmth in the winter, and a degree of comfort in their touch. Moreover, they are sometimes worn alone, for instance when playing sport–though it stands to reason that this does not give them any great importance, for it is the way of sportsmen to wear ‘undershirts’ alone.

What about a garment worn solely for ritual purposes.  For example, if one wraps oneself in an American flag on July 4th, it might be argued that the fact that it is visible gives it a "fashion"-like garment function.  But if there was an unusual (hypothetical) custom to hide the flag between one's undershirt and shirt, there would seem to be no garment-like function at all.

Accordingly, why would an otherwise functionless (at least on warm days) traditional *tallit katan* be obligated in *tzitzit*?  Is the reasoning that a garment functional in winter, is also considered a בגד when worn in summer?  Likewise, is a *tallit gadol* only obligated in tzitzit if simultaneously otherwise functional? (Similarly, would the same reasoning apply with regard to carrying on Shabbos and מצות קריעה?)

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/902223/rabbi-jonathan-ziring/halacha-al-regel-achat-tzitzit-when-wearing-a-flag/

Comment: According to 4 USC, the US flag should not be used as a garment.  So in that specific example the answer would be no.  I am curious about the general case.

Comment: I don't see what bringing a flag and July 4 into this helps at all. Just argue straight from undershirts to Talit Katan. Especially with such prominent titular placement it's really distracting

Comment: ... and case in point someone posted an answer showing they totally misunderstood the question. Please edit!!

Comment: @CodeswithHammer I see your legalese and raise you the First Amendment.

Comment: @DonielF: To quote a certain rav, 4 USC is "really more like guidelines anyway."  More on point, AIUI _tzitzit_ are for an item specifically intended to be a garment.

Comment: @DonielF Seems rather ironic to disrespect the U.S. flag on a day meant to respect it and what it stands for, First Amendment aside.

Comment: @ezra I wasn’t recommending it. All I said is that it’s legal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, perhaps a functionless tallit is not obligated in tzitzit. This seems to have been the opinion of R. [Avraham Yeshaya Karelitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Yeshaya_Karelitz), at least:

**[Shilhi Dekayta Siman 8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50015&st=&pgnum=45)**

> וכששטחתי את גליונות הספר קמיה מורי הגר"ח קניבסקי שליט"א אמר הגר"ח שגם
>   לדעתו אכן צריכים הנאת לבישה מהציצית וכן מוכח ממנהג החזו"א זצ"ל שהורה
>   שלא לילך בקיץ כציצית מצמר למרות שלדעת חלק מהראשונים דוקא ציצית זו
>   חייבת מדאוריתא בד' כנפות וכנראה דס"ל דכשמתענה מלבישתו אזי חסר בהנאת
>   הבגד ומשו"כ אי"ז בגד הראוי לציצית ואכן מן הראוי לפרסם סימן זה אך יש
>   להדגיש שהדברים אינם מוסכמים ולא בכל עת שרב אכן פטור מדינא מלבישת
>   הציצית

Earlier in the siman he cites other contemporary authorities. Apparently [R. Shlomo Zalman Auerbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Zalman_Auerbach) and [R. Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Pinchas_Scheinberg) disagreed, but [R. Yosef Shalom Elyashiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Shalom_Eliashiv) agreed that the garment needs to provide some sort of benefit.

Comment: This becomes a tremendous Chumra on Shabbat, fwiw.

Comment: +1   According to that reasoning, I would think a cotton beged should also be a problem if one is wearing two additional layers? (Interestingly, I believe Rav Mosher has a teshuva explicitly instructing a grandson to wear wool even in summer.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed. He mentions earlier in the piece that R. Moshe Feinstein permitted it on Shabbos even in the heat, stating that it's still considered a beged.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Jonathan Ziring, in the lecture linked to above by DoubleAA, brings a Machlokes between Rav Aviner, who allows people to wear an Israeli flag without adding Tzitzis, since it has the status of 'clothing for honor', which do not qualify as a beged for tzitzis, and Rav Ariel, who says that if one is wrapped in it (and it would fall under Ituf), you are actually required to put on Tzitzis.  However, it seems that it would still be frowned upon to enter into such a situation (both legally and in terms of the honor for such a symbol), and ideally, the corners should be rounded to avoid such an issue.

Others point out some other reasons for leniency, such as that there are not two corners in front and two in back - I personally don't see any reason why if someone is wearing it as a cape (or a tallis), that this leniency would apply, but it would apply if it is simply around their neck and all 4 corners are in the front.

Comment: While I sympathize with your apparent confusion, I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: +1 Interesting since I believe the design of the flag is actually supposed to have been based on the (striped) tallit.